# Isomorphism of finitely generated groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let G and H be two groups such that $G=<a,b>$, $H=<c,d>$ and o(a)=o(c), o(b)= o(d). Does that imply that G and H are isomorphic? or some other condition is also required ?

Answer (score 3):

Let $r$ and $s$ two lines in the plane through the origin, and denote with the same letters the reflections through them.

Then ${\rm ord}(r)={\rm ord}(s)=2$.

But the isomorphism type of the group $G=<r,s>$ depends strongly on the angle $\theta$ between $r$ and $s$.

If $\theta=\pi/4$ then $G=\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$. If $\theta\notin\Bbb Q\pi$ then $G$ is not even finite.